# Criar templates de documentos em Java

Tags: java, swing, template

Estou criando um sistema em Java com Swing, onde eu teria templates de documentos, e preencheria com dados informados pelo usuário num formulário que já criei, para que ele gere um PDF do template preenchido com os dados.

Tentei fazer de maneira "bruta", salvando o texto padrão em TXT, colocando "coringas" tipo, onde for data, eu inseri `$data$` e depois eu filtraria usando *pattern*, porém, vejo que desta forma se tornou inviável.

Como fazer estes templates de forma mais funcional?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/2X34a1jb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Melhor solução é utilizar um componente de geração de relatórios, como o Jasper.

Ele permite a criação de templates, seja em tempo de execução ou desenvolvimento. É bastante poderoso, e permite que os relatórios sejam exportados em vários formatos, inclusive PDF ou outro formato que você desenvolver.

Segue o site dele:

[Jasper Reports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library)

Comment: Por que não inclui um exemplo de como usá-lo? :)

Comment: Esta ferramenta funciona com java e swing ou é pra java EE? Digo porque a aplicação é desktop.

Comment: Eu sinceramente só utilizei ela em EE, mas não vejo motivos para ele não funcionar em aplicações desktop. A única diferença será nos data sources, que não serão beans, e sim collections normais. Procurando na internet, também não encontrei nada que indique o contrário, então assumo que funciona sim. De qualquer modo, não é complicado testar e descobrir.

Comment: Estou na dúvida, devo usar apenas a library sem o server, e funcionará normalmente?

Comment: Não entendi a pergunta. Você deve apenas incluir as classes do package `net.sf.jasperreports.engine`. Pelo menos estas são as classes que utilizo.

Comment: No link que você mandou, diz que tem que configurar um server para a API funcionar, porem meu app não pode usar server, é standalone, to usando HSQLDB justamente por este motivo.